# How to Delete Same Elements in Array in PHP

Tags: php

I have an array in php like

array(1,3,0,6,0,6,9,0);

I want to remove '0' elements from this array. and get array like that array(1,3,6,6,9) 
I am new user i cannot tell my question very well so sorry in advance please.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just googling for the title would have given you some pretty solid leads on how to solve this issue. Please always search and read previous solutions before asking. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Filters out all 0.

```
$array = array_filter($array);
```

Comment: yes got it dear from above ans and this is also nice thaxxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
<?php
    $arr = array(1,3,0,6,0,6,9,0);
    foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
    {
        if($v==0)
        {
            unset($arr[$k]);
        }
    }
    print_r($arr);
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 3
    [3] => 6
    [5] => 6
    [6] => 9
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be:

```
$arr = array(1,3,0,6,0,6,9,0);

$arr = array_filter($arr, function($el) { return $el != 0; });
```